Google tag manager em aplicação react
Adicionei o goggle tag manager em uma aplicação react com next 12 da seguinte maneira:
import TagManager from "react-gtm-module";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    const router = useRouter();

    // Google Tag Manager
    useEffect(() => {
        const tagManangerArgs = {
            gtmId: "meu_id"
        }

        
        TagManager.initialize(tagManangerArgs)

    }, [])

Consigo fazer a conexão, mas minha aplicação fica dando o erro: Unhandled Runtime Error
ReferenceError: googleFormValidation is not defined. Alguém sabe o que deve ser feito para corrigir esse erro?

Não tenho reputação para adicionar comentários por adiciono aqui.
Primeiro para inicializares Google Tag Manager deve ser fora do componente no root do projecto como visto na documentação.
Segue o exemplo: Usage
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Router from 'react-router'
import routes from './routes'

import TagManager from 'react-gtm-module'

const tagManagerArgs = {
    gtmId: 'GTM-000000'
}

TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs)

const app = document.getElementById('app')
ReactDOM.render(<Router routes={routes} />, app)

